# Permission denied to view directory

Tags: command-line, permissions, directory, gui, copy

I copied contents of my pendrive to a directory in mint machine. When I tried to click the copied contents through gui to view it said, "You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents". In the other thread it was said that I can view my file by elevating privileges to the gui by gksudo command but do I have to do that everytime i copy a file from an external source. What can be done?. I need to differently copy or add permissions to the directory?. Please let me know.

Comment: Well i changed ownership of those areas using chown command, that solved it for me!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `sudo chown yourUserName /path/to/folder` this will give you ownership of the directory if it was for some reason mounted as root. If this still doesn't work try `chmod +rwx /path/to/folder` which will allow reading and writing to that directory

Comment: Yea yea I did that like I mentioned. It worked thanks anyway :)

Comment: `sudo chmod +rwx /var/www/html` worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try going to the folder in file manager ,click on it ,then press the three dots and go to properties (ps three dots are on the upper navigation bar to the right),then check the owner and change it from root to your own username.